# How to pass a string parameter to an mbunit factory method?

Tags: unit-testing, factory, mbunit, gallio, data-driven-tests

I have a single function that generates variations for a series of unit tests given a string parameter. How can I use the factory attribute (or some alterative method) that takes additional takes a string paramater for the factory method?

I am using with Gallio/mbUnit for an automated test framework.

Answer (score 2):

```
[TestFixture]
public class SampleFixture
{
   [Column("123", "456")] 
   private string parameter; // Causes the fixture to be run once for each value.

   public IEnumerable<string> GetData()
   {
      yield return "abc" + parameter;
      yield return "def" + parameter;
      yield return "ghi" + parameter;
   }

   [Test, Factory("GetData")]
   public void MyDataDrivenTest(string text)
   {
      TestLog.WriteLine(text);
   }
}
```

You might want to read the articles about [data-driven tests](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3adata-driven_testing) in the [**Gallio wiki**](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=start). You will find many examples explaining how to use `[Row]`, `[Column]`, and other convenient features for creating data-driven tests with MbUnit.

**UPDATE**: In the example above, I've just concatenated the data from the factory with the external parameter. Thus the test will be run 6 times ("abc123", "def123", "ghi123", "abc456", "def456", and "ghi456"). But you could just use the parameter in another way; such as modifying the whole behavior of `GetData`.

Comment: Thanks; but my question is how to pass, in your example, a string to GetData method so it can determine what to return as test data.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand exactly. GetData can return whatever you want, and not be necessarily a list of yield returns. For example, it can grab data from an external data source such as a repository, a custom generator, or any sort of data factory. Maybe you could provide an example of what you want to achieve. Where that string parameter comes from? User input, database, config files?

Comment: I want to call a method which accepts a string and returns an IEnumerable<object[]> for the unit test. The method needs to be passed a string for it to generate the data - basically it generates a whole bunch of permutations based on the given string. So what I was looking for was an attribute like this: [Test, Factory("GetData"), "123"] which calls the method IEnumerable<string> GetData(string key) with "123" for key.

Comment: Note: I did work around the issue by writing a custom data source attribute, as your described on your blog. Thanks.

Comment: I understand. A custom data source might help indeed. Otherwise, you could use a simple extern test parameter (a fixture field for example) bound to a data source (a column or whatever). Then you can use that parameter from GetData or from any test method. I've updated my answer accordingly.